# Time discrepancy between 'dmesg' and 'date' in Linux

Tags: c, linux, date, linux-kernel, vmware

I have some kernel module which prints to log like

```
printk(KERN_INFO "Something\n");
```

When module was loaded I found that the time in `dmesg` outruns the current time in `date`:

```
-bash-4.4$ dmesg -T | grep some_driver
[Sat May 16 22:25:03 2020] some_driver: Something
-bash-4.4$ date
Sat May 16 22:22:02 UTC 2020
```

What could be the reason?

P.S. Linux kernel version is 4.4, it lives in VMware vSphere VM.

Comment: `UTC` So what is your locale? Are both commands used in the same terminal with the same locale? Was the system ever suspended? What would be the output of `dmesg --time-format=iso`?

Comment: @KamilCuk I can't see the info in log about possible suspensions, but I did snapshots several times by myself. Yep, both commands used one by one in single terminal. The same offset with `dmesg --time-format=iso`. What exactly you need to know about locale? It's a set of env variables..

Comment: `The same offset` but what timezone? `It's a set of env variables..` that affect how date is displayed. And affect daylight saving time.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html says "Be aware that the timestamp could be inaccurate!  The time source used for the logs is not updated after system SUSPEND/RESUME"

Comment: @KamilCuk `dmesg --time-format=iso` line looks like `2020-05-16T22:52:07,658967+0000 ......`

Comment: The same man page says "The iso format has the same issue as ctime: the time may be inaccurate when a system is suspended and resumed.".  That implies to me that the other formats would be accurate.

Comment: The time could be corrected by a user space utility once the system has booted. Or by vmware-tools for example.

Comment: In my `dmesg -T`, I have `PM: RTC time: 23:42:03, date: 2020-05-16`, do you have similar message ?

Comment: @Cheatah I'm the only user since last boot. If vmware tools are to blame, I will presumably see the same thing in other VMs, but no..

Comment: @Philippe I don't understand what exactly are you asking? I have no such strings `PM: RTC time: 23:42:03, date: 2020-05-16` in my `dmesg -T`.

Comment: If you restart your VM , do you have the same behaviour ?

Comment: @Philippe Seems that there is no such problem just after reboot. But obviously the problem is present after reverting to the particular snapshot.

Comment: @red0ct did you see the link to the man page?  It says right there the time is inaccurate.  Did you try another format?

Comment: @user2740650 Yep, I see. So what? You mean I should post it as answer? Or delete my question?

Comment: @red0ct entirely up to you, but it seems like you're fighting against documented behaviour.

Comment: @user2740650 Why you think I'm "fighting"? Did I mind what is indicated in the MAN?